# Java - Merge sort with Strings

Tags: java, sorting, merge, mergesort, indexoutofboundsexception

In this program, I am sorting Olympic medals using mergeSort.

Something seems a little off with my code since sometimes it will give me an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and sometimes, it won't.

---

For a little background explanation:

I have a method that randomly generates Olympic countries and their medals won in a scoreboard. Returns a String[] array of results in the form of:

**CAN 1 1 1**

**USA 1 1 2**

**GBR 0 0 1**

**CHN 0 0 2**

---

However the scoreboard needs to be organized y descending medals of gold, silver and bronze. So it would have to be like:

**USA 1 1 2**

**CAN 1 1 1**

**CHN 0 0 2**

**GBR 0 0 1**

Using  bubblesort and quicksort to sort the board works fine, but mergesort does not. At times it will be fine, but more often of the time it gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    

  Olympic_Results score = new Olympic_Results();

  //print a return value of an array    

  String[] countries = score.OlympicResult(7); //input how many game results
  mergeSort(countries, 0, countries.length - 1);
  for (String value:countries)
  System.out.println(value);
}

public static void mergeSort(String array[], int lo, int n) {
  int low = lo;
  int high = n;
  if (low >= high) {
    return;
  }

  int middle = (low + high) / 2;
  mergeSort(array, low, middle);
  mergeSort(array, middle + 1, high);
  int end_low = middle;
  int start_high = middle + 1;
  while ((lo <= end_low) && (start_high <= high)) {
    if ((array[low].substring(4,8)).compareTo(array[high].substring(4,8)) > 0) {
      low++;
    } 

    else {
      String Temp = array[start_high];
      for (int k = start_high - 1; k >= low; k--) {
        array[k + 1] = array[k];
      }
      array[low] = Temp;
      low++;
      end_low++;
      start_high++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Any idea why this code isn't working properly? Thank you!**

Comment: What line does the stack trace point too?

Comment: Some side comments: methods and variables in Java are normally `camelCase`. Classes are normally `TitleCase` without underscores.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Why do you want to merge sort? Isn't the most important thing just that it's sorted? I would use Array.sort().

Comment: @CodeChimp I believe this is the stack trace: 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 (this number changes each time)
 at main.mergeSort(main.java:58)
 at main.mergeSort(main.java:54)
 at main.main(main.java:33)

Comment: @Bohemian I'm learning about the sorting algorithms right now, so I have to go through each algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you go down too deep in dividing the array into parts:

```
if (low >= high) {
    return;
    }
```

Try to start fixing it with stopping here when length is 1.

```
if (high - low <=1) {
    return;
    }
```

BTW, if the length is 2 then you can compare the values in place and return them already sorted immediately.

**UPD**

You seem to add too many variables with similar names and lost yourself in them :)..

This does not look correct :

while ((**lo** <= end_low) && (start_high <= high)) {

Answer (score 0):

Two major errors:

1. You keep two variables with similar names, but different purpose. As a result the `while` loop test the `lo` value, despite never changing it (the loop works with `low` variable).
2. The `if` inside `while` should compare the initial items of two sorted series to choose one of them. Your series start at `low` and `start_high`, so you should compare `array[low]` to `array[start_high]`, but you compare it to `array[high]` instead. If `array[high]` data happens to be the smallest in the subinterval being sorted, then the `low` value will get incremented past the array size (and `while` condition doesn't catch it, as it tests `lo` instead).